Graphics crash after installing ROCM in Ubuntu 24.04
I have been having issues installing rocm on my Ubuntu 24.04. Every time I follow the documentation for the rocm install everything seems to work fine until I reboot, then the graphics starts glitching out and my desktop screens flicker, and I can't even open the terminal so it's effectively breaking the entire system.
I got rocm running successfully once by adding the jammy repository and then installing rocm, I was able to run stable diffusion as a test so I know it works at least one way. First of all I don’t really know if my machine could run into issues in the future having the jammy repository added, so I would prefer to install the normal way the documentation shows.
For reference, the only time I got rocm working was following this answer ROCm not working on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop
I thought that the issue was that I had secure boot on, however even after trying twice with secure boot off and reflashing my Ubuntu boot drive, I still have the issue.I also had changed the setting in the BIOS to not prioritize my integrated graphics card on boot which I thought could be the issue as well, but I still have that setting prioritizing my PEG.
Does anyone know how to solve this? It seems too straightforward and the documentation is so simple (I also had no issues installing rocm on this machine previously on 22.04. In the worst case, I will add the jammy repository again and just use it this way for now, but as I previously stated I would prefer doing everything the standard/default way so I don;t run into weird issues like this…
Specs:
CPU: AMD 7950x3d
GPU: 7900xtx
Ubuntu 24.04
The commands I used for install from official documentation are as follows:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install "linux-headers-$(uname -r)" "linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)"
sudo usermod -a -G render,video $LOGNAME # Add the current user to the render and video groups
wget https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/6.2/ubuntu/noble/amdgpu-install_6.2.60200-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./amdgpu-install_6.2.60200-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms rocm

